# Ionic reaction between lithium and chlorine

Tags: ions, electronic-configuration, erratum

I got a weird question in my chemistry book. It says Li and Cl react to form LiCl an ionic compound. Cl has .... electrons in its outermost occupied shell and the answer of the book is 6 electrons . How?

Comment: Book is wrong. Chlorine has 7 valence electrons.

Comment: Unless of course the book meant the p-shells only and the resulting ion. Which would be weird as hell.

Comment: @Jan - it would be p "subshell" then, although I wouldn't put it past a book that says chlorine has 6 valence electrons to mix up shell and subshell...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your book is wrong. It can't be. There has to be 8 electrons in the outermost occupied shell and to complete its octet. I searched over the google about it and found three links to cover my answer.

1. https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111018173152AAn9DHz
2. https://quizlet.com/38997670/chem-1305-exam-2-study-guide-flash-cards/ (question number 3)
3. http://slidegur.com/doc/1661637/ionic-bonds (slide number 18)

Comment: Chloride has 8 valence electrons, chlorine has 7. Btw, I don't think it's really necessary to cite sources for this kind of thing... but if you really want to cite sources, please try to choose more reliable sources. Even though people always like to say "Wikipedia is unreliable", it is not a bad start.

Comment: @orthocresol that's why i chose to take three sources. How much probability is there that all three of them would be wrong. I would have commented them but due to lack of reputation points, i couldn't.

Comment: You can can comment under your own post

Comment: @Mithoron Now i can comment anywhere..lol...i have just got the 'comment everywhere' privilege

Comment: That was fast :D You can also use chat now :)